# Is there a QAbstractFileEngine with in memory caching in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

QAbstractFileEngine can be used in QT to abstract access to a file system. I am searching for a way to prevent access to a file system by keeping files in memory after a first access. Further attempts to open a QFile should then operate directly on the memory handle.

This has been kind of done for both Android and IOS:

- http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/plain/src/plugins/platforms/ios/qiosfileengineassetslibrary.mm
- http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/android/qandroidassetsfileenginehandler.cpp

Any one know an existing caching implementation of QFSFileEngine?

Comment: In the days of SSDs and all modern file system implementations keeping a file system cache in virtual memory, do you really need this...? What platform are you targetting? There might have been other reasons this has been implemented on Android and iOS: Likely startup performance and/or platform restrictions.

Comment: Our main UI thread fails to achieve 60 Hz refresh rate and one of the things we are seeing are the filesystem accesses to images referred from CSS when the user moves over buttons. This causes QT to reload images from the filesystem and seems wasteful (filesystem locks and all).

Comment: Where does the CSS come from? You might want to have a look at [QRC files](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: Would be another way to do it, but our CSS is currently primarily linking to files (in particular during development). Still, would that be caching?

Comment: The files contained in the QRC are compiled into an object file and linked to your executable/library. So, yes, it's all in memory after application startup.